# How to add the 'AND' condition in dynamic query for multi select picklists?

Tags: apex, soql, multi-select

```
List<String> newMultiSelectList = new List<String>();
newMultiSelectList.add('Pro-Life');
newMultiSelectList.add('Establishment');
newMultiSelectList.add('GOP');

string value = '(\'' + String.join(newMultiSelectList, '\',\'')+'\')';

String queryString = 'select id, Audience_Tags__c FROM Audience__c WHERE Audience_Tags__c INCLUDES'+value;

List<Audience__c> newlist = DataBase.query(queryString);
//Getting all the results which has any of the values from the list
// I need resluts which includes all the three values
system.debug('List of records: '+newlist);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_querying_multiselect_picklists.htm), have you tried...

```
String value = '(\'' + String.join(newMultiSelectList, ';') + '\')';
```

Answer (score 3):

It'd be easier to just use a binding:

```
string value = String.join(newMultiSelectList, ';');

String queryString = 'select id, Audience_Tags__c FROM Audience__c WHERE Audience_Tags__c INCLUDES (:value)';
```

You don't actually need a dynamic query for this:

```
Audience__c[] newlist = [select id, Audience_Tags__c FROM Audience__c WHERE Audience_Tags__c INCLUDES (:value)];
```